# VB, Pass variables to a control

Tags: vb.net, variables, controls

I have been tasked with creating a cinema booking system in VB.net by my teacher. So far I have created 50 CheckBoxes and I am trying to rename them all to seat (number). I have this code in my Form1.load but it is not working because it is a type and not an expression. I tried using a variable for this but it did not work.

Here is my code:

```vb
        For count As Integer = 1 To 54 Step 1
            CheckBox(count).text = "Seat " & count
        Next
```

Please help, and or recommend me another way to accomplish this.

Comment: Changing the `.Text` does not change the name, just the `.Text` displayed.  What is `Checkbox()` an array or is it supposed to represent one of the 50+ checkboxes?  VB.NET does not natively support Control arrays.  Also, turn on `Option Strict`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the name of the checkbox when you create it.  To find out how to create a checkbox programmatically add a checkbox to a form then look at .designer.vb

```
dim cb as new checkbox
cb.name = "1"
cb.text = "Seat 1"
```

you need to also add the location and other properties

If you have already created your textboxes with names like 1, 2 then iterate through and get the numbers like this:  If you call them CB_1 then cut the CB_ off before looking for the number.

```
dim cbNumber as int16

For Each c As Control In myContainer.Controls
    If c.GetType() Is GetType(CheckBox) Then
       cbnumber = cint(c.name)
       c.text = "Seat" & cbnumber 
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I'll bet the OP wants "Seat 25" between #24 and #26 which your code wont assure

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's my approach. In order to test just drop on a `FlowLayoutPanel`, a `Button`, and a `NumericUpDown`onto the form.

```
Option Strict On

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For count As Integer = 1 To 54 Step 1
            ' Make a new CheckBox
            Dim chkBox As New CheckBox()
            ' Setup the Checkbox
            With chkBox
                .Tag = count.ToString
                .Name = CStr("seatCheckBox" & count.ToString)
                .Text = String.Format("Seat {0}", count)
                .ThreeState = False
                .Checked = False
            End With

            ' add an event listener for the checkbox checkstate changed event
            AddHandler chkBox.CheckStateChanged, AddressOf Me.CheckBox_CheckStateChanged

            ' Add the checkbox to the control
            Me.FlowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(chkBox)

            ' Keep the user from picking something that doesn't exist
            Me.NumericUpDown1.Maximum = CDec(count)
        Next

        ' Add and event listener for the find button click event
        AddHandler Button1.Click, AddressOf Me.FindButton_Clicked

    End Sub

    ' Find the checkbox in the form and return it
    Private Function GetCheckBox(ByVal seatNumber As Integer) As CheckBox
        Dim chkbox As CheckBox

        ' Try to find the Checkbox
        Try
            chkbox = TryCast(Me.Controls.Find(CStr("seatCheckBox" & seatNumber.ToString), True).First, CheckBox)
        Catch ex As Exception
            chkbox = Nothing
        End Try

        'Check if the trycast worked
        If IsNothing(chkbox) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("seatNumber", "The seat number to be searched for was not found")
        Else
            Return chkbox
        End If

    End Function

    ' Handle the Chekbox checkState event.
    Private Sub CheckBox_CheckStateChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Convert to Checkbox
        Dim chkBox As CheckBox = DirectCast(sender, CheckBox)

        ' Simple result string
        Dim resultstring As String = CStr("Seat Number {0} is now {1}.")

        ' Set the values
        Select Case chkBox.Checked
            Case True
                resultstring = String.Format(resultstring, chkBox.Tag, "taken")
            Case False
                resultstring = String.Format(resultstring, chkBox.Tag, "available")
        End Select

        ' Display it
        MsgBox(resultstring)
    End Sub

    Private Sub FindButton_Clicked(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try
            ' Get the checkbox and return it's name
            MsgBox(GetCheckBox(CInt(Me.NumericUpDown1.Value)).Name.ToString)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Display the error
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```